# if statement, modify output

Tags: mysql, database, if-statement

What will be the SQL statement for this scenario ?

```
tbl_user_account

id INT(11)
name varchar(100)
username varchar(25)
password varchar(25)
active int(1)


_____________________________________
|id|name | username|password  |active|
_____________________________________
|1 |John | jhon123 | p@ssw0rd | 1  | 
|2 |Maria| maria321| p@ss     | 0  |
```

I wanted to fetch all the record but the active field must output 
"YES" if it's 1 or "No" if it's 0

I wanted this OUTPUT :

---

```
|id|name | username|password  |active|
_____________________________________
|1 |John | jhon123 | p@ssw0rd | Yes  | 
|2 |Maria| maria321| p@ss     | No  |
```

do I need to create a function or just simply an if statement?

Comment: Note that `int(1)` -- the `1` doesn't actually limit anything, it's only used for display. You might consider using the `BOOL` type (which is actually a synonym for `TINYINT(1)`) but you're still saving 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id, name, username, password, if (active >0, "YES", "NO") from table_name
```

Comment: select * from tbl_user_account if(active >0,"YES","NO") ?

Comment: I'd simplify that to `IF(active,'YES','NO')`. The `>0` doesn't really do anything here... MySQL likes 1s and 0s for booleans.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, name, username, password,
  CASE active
    WHEN 0 THEN "no"
    WHEN 1 THEN "yes"
    ELSE "Umm" 
  END 
FROM tbl_user_account
```